# Derivative of the symplectomorphism evaluated at a point of the zero section of the cotangent bundle

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, lagrangian-submanifolds, cotangent-bundles

It might be an easy question, possibly not worth posting here. In the proof of the *Lagrangian neighborhood theorem*, the authors have written the expression for the derivative of a symplectomorphism at a point of the zero section. I don't understand how one arrives at this expression.

Let $L$ be a Lagrangian submanifold of the symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$. Choose an almost complex structure $J\colon TM\to TM$ compatible with $\omega$. Thus $g_J:=\omega(-,J\cdot)$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$.

Define $\phi\colon T^*L\to M$ as follows $\phi(q, v^*)=\exp_q\left(J_q \Phi_q(v^*)\right)$, where $g_J\left(\Phi_q(v^*),v\right)=v^*(v)$.

> Question 1: I think $\phi$ can't be defined on whole $T^*L$, shouldn't the domain of definition of $\phi$ is an open subset of the zero section $L\subset T^*L$?

> Question 2: Why $d\phi_{(q,0)}(v_0,v_1^*)=v_0+J_q\Phi_q(v_1^*)$, where
> $(v_0,v_1^*)\in T_qL\oplus T^*_qL=T_{(q,0)}T^*L$?

Note that $J(TL)$ is the normal bundle $NL$ of $L$ in $M$ w.r.t. $g_J$.

*Reference:*
Introduction to Symplectic Topology
by Dusa McDuff, Dietmar Salamon; see [page 121](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Symplectic_Topology/cjddDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Theorem+3.4.13+(Lagrangian+neighbourhood+theorem)+Let+(M,+%CF%89)+be+a+symplectic+manifold+and+L+%E2%8A%82+M+be+a+compact+Lagrangian+submanifold.&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Question 1, $\phi$ can be defined on the whole of $T^*L$ so long as the exponential map can be defined on the normal bundle $NL$, which will be the case for example if $M$ is geodesically complete. It is not generally 1-1 on $T^*L$, but is on a neighbourhood of the zero section $L$ - is this possibly what you were thinking?

On Question 2, $\phi(q,0) = q \implies d\phi_{(q,0)}(v_0,0) = v_0$ while $$d\phi_{(q,0)}(0,v_1^*) =\frac{d}{dt}\Big\vert_{t=0}\phi(q,tv_1^*) = \frac{d}{dt}\Big\vert_{t=0}\exp_q(tJ_q\Phi_q(v_1^*)) =  J_q\Phi_q(v_1^*)$$ by definition of the exponential map.